# beginners book on analog circuits

Tags: analog, books, circuit-analysis

As a scientist, I have a good theoretical grasp on the quantum mechanics behind a diode/pn-junction, capacitors, inductors etc.. however, I have practically no hands-on experience with designing an analog circuit.

As a consequence, I would like to read a book on basic analog circuit design which emphasizes practice, not theory. Roughly speaking, I am looking for a book aimed at engineers, not physicists. Any good recommendations?

Comment: Analogue circuit books aimed at engineers would likely contain a decent amount of theory/formulas/calculations on how a particular circuit works and how it can be applied so these can't be called "basic". Are you looking for a beginner's guide?

Comment: Stuff by Bob Pease or Jim Williams is a decent bet, as are their various writings (many of which are available on Linear Tec's website)

Comment: The field of analogue design is immense ranging from simple one or two transistor circuits to hifi audio amps to oscillators to RF to... etc. etc. Rather than going for a book (which at best will only give you more theory) why not find a few small projects **to make** (plenty of free sources on the net or kits) and then analyze how it works. Any electronic design, no matter how complex, is made up from simple (smaller) circuits. The trick is knowing how to connect them all up.

Comment: to read the articles of bob pease [1.ELECTRONIC DESIGN MAGAZINE][1]  [2.TEXAS INSTRUMENTS][2] [3.Youtube bob pease show][3]

Jim williams [links to Linear technology app notes][4]


  [1]: http://electronicdesign.com/author/bob-pease
  [2]: http://www.ti.com/ww/en/bobpease/
  [3]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zy5z1esPkqo&list=PL59089C08F42536A4
  [4]: http://readingjimwilliams.blogspot.in/

Comment: dear niles_1710373, Sorry for the inconvenience caused by this forum. people here in this forum dont like these kind of questions and even no room for absolute beginners.so please go to www.edaboard.com (there are so many sections like electronic elementary questions)

Comment: There are several other threads like this of EE SE, why is this any different and fit for being closed? @yogece thanks for the kind replies

Comment: You may want to check out Paul Scherz' "Practical Electronics for Inventors"

Answer (score 2):

While not a book, I found All About Circuits to be a good place to start. It was recommended to me by a friend going to school for EE. The website can be found here; http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/